# Use of "homeostasis"

Tags: meaning

> I'm going to  say what's on my mind and it just might affect your
>   **homeostasis**.

Is *homeostasis* correctly used?

Comment: Why do you doubt it?

Comment: Can you give a lot more context?

Comment: yes, more context please? Is this spoken? Written? In a scientific context? Uttered by a psychologist? If this is just normal dialog between average people, this usage would be unusual or confusing. If it's a psychologist talking to a patient, it might be fine, for example.

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, but it depends on context.

It is unlikely that anything you say will affect my body's [homeostatic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homeostasis) ability to maintain its temperature, blood pH levels or blood glucose.

If you mean it metaphorically (perhaps you are going to be so provocative that I might lose my normal high level of self-control), then I need to understand that that is what you mean, and I probably would not.

Comment: When my girlfriend told me that she was going to Iraq to meet someone she had been talking to for a couple of months it totally effected my homeostasis... but you are right, in 40 years, there have not been many times where that has happened. We will need to know what was meant by "homeostasis" to know if it was used correctly, but grammatically it is correct.

Comment: Every one of those parameters can, and usually, will be effected by statements that you hear, to an extent, and that, you may or may not be aware of.

Comment: There's no metaphor here.

Answer (score 1):

I'd go with

> I'm going to say what's on my mind, and it just might affect your ability to maintain homeostasis.

Comment: "... maintain homeostasis"? Homeostasis *is* 'maintaining equilibrium'.

Comment: Homeostasis exists when an organism’s internal state is in balance, even when the outside environment is changing. So, yes, it can be correct to say *maintain homeostasis*, just as it is correct to say *maintain equilibrium*.

Comment: Obviously, you're stuck with one sense of the word. Suggest you look up the definitions -- they make for an interesting read.

Answer (score 1):

Probably yes, although this usage does not seem usual.

The NOAD defines *homeostasis* as follow:

> the tendency toward a relatively stable equilibrium between
>   interdependent elements, [...]

Further, Dictionary.com for *homeostasis* report that:

> [...]
>   Psychology. *a state of psychological equilibrium obtained when tension
>   or a drive has been reduced or eliminated*. 
>   [...]

So, the sentence you have mentioned makes sense whether the word *homeostasis* has psychological meaning<sup>(1)</sup>.

---

<sup>(1)</sup>*[American Psychological Association](http://psycnet.apa.org/journals/rev/49/1/80/): "Cannon originated the term homeostasis to describe the tendency of organisms to maintain stability or uniformity in their body states. By an extension of the principle, it might be used to describe the already demonstrated tendency to maintain status at the mental level of behavior [...]"*

Comment: Those are technical uses, especially the second one which states it is a psychology term. If the context is not a technical one, then readers are very likely to be confused or at least taken aback. This might be writer's intention, though. Without context who can say?

Comment: Speaking technically, homeostasis isn't about 'equilibrium' at all. It's about steady-state. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steady_state_%28chemistry%29  A biological system at equilibrium with its environment is dead. Living systems exist far from equilibrium, and maintain steady state values of temperature/glucose etc. In steady state systems, there's a continual flow of material from reactant to product. In equilibrium systems, the net flow is zero.

Comment: @Wayfaring "A biological system at equilibrium with its environment is dead." +1 for deadpan humor

Comment: So, the statement can be rephrased: "I'm going to say what's on my mind and it just might knock you off balance."